# ¿Por que se realiza varias llamadas a un metodo en FutureBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo un `FutureBuilder` que tiene un estructura básica.

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: api.sincronizacion(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
         ...
      })
```

El problema que presento es que por alguna extraña razón ejecuta mínimo 2 veces el método `sincronizacion()`, esto ocasiona que me genere errores con algunos otros métodos como inserciones a la base de datos con un mismo `id` que al ser `PRIMARY KEY` genera una excepción.

### Una de las excepciones que se recibe.

> SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(UNIQUE constraint failed: versions._id (code 1555 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY[1555])) sql 'INSERT INTO versions (_id, estabilidad, versionMayor, versionMenor, revision) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' args [5dc08909cad9c242119da306, beta, 1, 0, 12]})

Otra de las excepciones que se llega a presentar

> Exception has occurred. SqfliteDatabaseException
> (DatabaseException(database_closed 1))

---

## Ejemplo Sencillo

Este ejemplo simula la ejecución de manera sencilla de lo cual yo creo que es el problema con el `Future` utilizando una variable `number` para contar la cantidad de veces que entra al método sin reiniciar la instancia.

**Al final de la carga en data regresa 3,2 y en una ocasión 4** lo cual solo debería ser 1 por que se espera solo 1 llamada al método `_getData` que incrementa `number`

### main.dart

```
void main() => runApp(MyMaterialApp());

class MyMaterialApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Ejecutando MyMaterialApp');
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SplashLoad(),
    );
  }
}

class SplashLoad extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _SplashLoadState createState() => _SplashLoadState();
}

class _SplashLoadState extends State<SplashLoad> {
  final apiSimulation = new ApiSimulation();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('SplashScreen');
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: apiSimulation.sincronizacion(),
            // initialData: InitialData,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text('Carga completa data:${snapshot.data}');
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### ApiSimulation

simula un poco lo que sería la llamada de unos 4 segundos para obtener datos de un servidor y agregarlos a una base de datos.

```
class ApiSimulation {
  int number = 0;
  Future<int> sincronizacion()async{
    print('INICIANDO SINCRONIZACIÓN');
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    final data = await _getData();
    return data;
  }

  Future<int> _getData() async{
    number++;
    print('ejecutando getData$number');
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
    return number;
  }
}
```

### Resultado en consola

```
I/flutter (32404): Ejecutando MyMaterialApp
I/flutter (32404): SplashScreen
I/flutter (32404): INICIANDO SINCRONIZACIÓN
I/flutter (32404): Ejecutando MyMaterialApp
I/flutter (32404): SplashScreen
I/flutter (32404): INICIANDO SINCRONIZACIÓN
I/flutter (32404): ejecutando getData1
I/flutter (32404): ejecutando getData2
```

**Fin de ejemplo**

---

### He realizado múltiples pruebas

- Seguir la ejecución del código linea por linea con la herramienta de **VisualStudioCode**
- Cambiar la implementación del método de `static Future<List> sincronizacion() async {...` a `Future<List> sincronizacion() async {` por si acaso ayuda
- Modificar mi `main` pensando que el como se llamaba a la interfaz ocasionara que se llame 2 veces y eso al mismo tiempo ejecutar nuevamente `sincronizacion()`

  - Anteriormente

    ```
    MaterialApp(
        localizationsDelegates: [CustomLocalizationDelegate()],
        routes: getApplicationRoutes(),
        home: MyApp(),
        ...
    ```
  - Después donde `getApplicationRoutes()` contiene `MyApp()` en la ruta `'/'`

    ```
    MaterialApp(
        localizationsDelegates: [CustomLocalizationDelegate()],
        routes: getApplicationRoutes(),
        initialRoute: '/',
        ...
    ```

---

Las siguientes clases y métodos son de mi proyecto que presenta el problema.

### main

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final auth = Auth();
  final prefs = new PreferenciasApp(); //singleton
  await prefs.initPrefs();

  runApp(Provider(
    auth: auth,
    child: MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [CustomLocalizationDelegate()],
      routes: getApplicationRoutes(),
      initialRoute: '/',
      theme: ThemeData(...),
    ),
  ));
}
```

### getApplicationRoutes() en archivo routes.dart

```
// imports
...

final main = MyApp();
final home = Home(selectBottom: 0,);
final registro = Registro();
final inicioSesion = InicioSesionPlussUltraPower();
final playlist = PlaylisPage();
final inicio = Inicio();
final detallePlay = DetallePlay();

Map<String, WidgetBuilder> getApplicationRoutes() {    
  return <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    "/"           : (BuildContext context) => main,
    "/Himnario"           : (BuildContext context) => home,
    "/Registro"           : (BuildContext context) => registro,
    "/Inicio de sesión"   : (BuildContext context) => inicioSesion,
    "/PlayList"           : (BuildContext context) => playlist,
    "/Inicio"             : (BuildContext context) => inicio,
    DetallePlay.routeName : (BuildContext context) => detallePlay,
  };
}
```

### MyApp

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final prefs = new PreferenciasApp();
  final api = new ApiService();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Ejecutando myApp------------------------->>>>>');
    
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: api.sincronizacion(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final result = snapshot.data;

          if (result[0] == null) {
            return Container(...),
            );

          } else {
            text = result[0] ? 'Carga completa' : 'Error en la carga.';
            var page = prefs.idUser.isEmpty ? Inicio() : InicioSesion();
            return SplashScreen(
               seconds: 1,
               navigateAfterSeconds: page,
               ...
            );
          }
        } //snapshot.hasData

        return Container(...);
      },
    ); // FutureBuilder
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 cosas:

1- Convierte `MyApp` en StatefulWidget.

2- Extrae `final prefs = new PreferenciasApp();` y `final api = new ApiService();` afuera del método `build` y dentro del State que crearás.

3- Saca las variables que tienes dentro del método `getApplicationRoutes`.

```dart
Map<String, WidgetBuilder> getApplicationRoutes() {
  
  final main = MyApp();
  final home = Home(selectBottom: 0,);
  final registro = Registro();
  final inicioSesion = InicioSesionPlussUltraPower();
  final playlist = PlaylisPage();
  final inicio = Inicio();
  final detallePlay = DetallePlay();
```

Estas recreando el `ApiService` por lo que el `FutureBuilder` detecta que son diferentes instancias y métodos al que estás llamando.

**UPDATE**

Luego de una pequeña investigación, encontré que hay 2 errores, pero de Flutter.

1- Por algún motivo el widget root se está refrescando muchas veces, dejo el link reportado que fue cerrado sin motivo: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23063

2- El FutureBuilder está recreando el future, esto no debería pasar, si bien el punto 1 podría suceder, pero el `FutureBuilder` debería mantener el future que se ejecutó y no volver a ejecutarlo.

**Solución**

Extrae el `Future` en el `initState`, de la siguiente manera.

```dart
class _SplashLoadState extends State<SplashLoad> {
  final apiSimulation = new ApiSimulation();
  Future<int> _value;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _value = apiSimulation.sincronizacion();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('SplashScreen');
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<int>(
            future: _value,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text('Carga completa data:${snapshot.data}');
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Aplícalo a tu proyecto y si funciona nos cuentas :).

Comment: Funciono perfectamente con el ejemplo al igual que con mi proyecto principal, Supongo que el problema del futureBuilder sera solucionado en próximas versiones o cambiara la forma en la que se debe utilizar.

Comment: @Richard podrian limpiar la tira de comentario, y dejar solo los que realmente aporten algo? gracias

Comment: @gbianchi los limpiaron todos :O