# ¿Como mostrar CircularProgress al cambiar opcion en un Future?

Tags: flutter, dart

Quiero mostrar en un `ListView` datos obtenidos con diferentes métodos de ordenamiento para lo cual utilizo una variable(`_orden`) para indicar que orden tendrá la lista.

Método de forma resumida,que realiza la consulta en el `orden` indicado

```
Future <List> getdb(int orden) async {
    final db = await database;

      final query = orden == 2
        ? "CONSULTA 1"
        : orden == 3 
        ? "CONSULTA 2"
        : "CONSULTA 3";

      final list = await db.rawQuery(query);
      
      return list;
    
}
```

Mi `Future` y `FutureBuilder`

```
Future<List> _myFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _myFuture = DBProvider.db.getAllHimnos(_orden);
    super.initState();
  }

FutureBuilder(
    future: _myFuture,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        
        final List data = snapshot.data;

        return ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          // ...mi codigo
        },
          
        );  
      }
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.blue),
        ),
      );
    },
)
```

Cambio de `_myFuture` para cambiar a un nuevo método de ordenamiento.

```
setState((){
    _orden = i-1;
    _myFuture = DBProvider.db.getAllHimnos(_orden);
});
```

**El problema** esta en que al cambiar `_myFuture` no muestra un `CircularProgressIndicator` en pantalla, realiza correctamente la consulta y cambia el listado, pero hay 1 o 2 consultas que tarda un poco mas en mostrar los datos, por lo que da la sensación de que no se esta realizando la acción seleccionada.

También con la consulta que tarda un poco mas que las otras me muestra los siguientes mensajes en consola.
Lo cual no se si es causado por la misma razon o tiene otra cosa que ver con la consulta?.

```
W/CursorWindow(15850): Window is full: requested allocation 327 bytes, free space 60 bytes, window size 4194304 bytes
W/CursorWindow(15850): Window is full: requested allocation 540 bytes, free space 500 bytes, window size 4194304 bytes
W/CursorWindow(15850): Window is full: requested allocation 88 bytes, free space 58 bytes, window size 4194304 bytes
I/eselfaro.himni(15850): Background concurrent copying GC freed 101153(17MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(27MB) LOS objects, 15% free, 131MB/155MB, paused 90us total 121.726ms
```

Comment: podrías revisar esta pregunta/respuesta : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/470646/por-que-se-realiza-varias-llamadas-a-un-metodo-en-futurebuilder

Comment: @diegoveloper he revisado lo que dices, he intentado utilizar el `Future` declarado en `initState` pero si lo hago de esa manera deja de funcionar el cambio de `_orden`

Comment: tendrías que recrear el Future y hacer un setState

Comment: @diegoveloper ok, por lo que entendí fue hacerlo de la siguiente manera `setState((){ _myFuture = DBProvider.db.getAllHimnos(_orden); });`
Soluciona el problema de cambiar  `_orden` pero sigue sin mostrar el circular al cambiarlo y como una de la consultas tarda un poco mas que los otros métodos de ordenamiento, da sensación de que se atoro

Comment: te recomendaría evitar el FutureBuilder, revisa los videos que tengo en mi canal sobre gestion de estado , mi canal : diegoveloper

Comment: @diegoveloper Muchas gracias, lo revisare para poder mostrar el circular al momento de cambiar el método de ordenamiento en el `Future`